# How do I run Starcraft 2 on an Asus Eee PC netbook?

Tags: starcraft-2

I know it doesn't meet the minimum specs but there [is a video of it working](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYBUn_NUBAg) and I'm willing to delve into some workarounds to make this happen.  It installed without error but gave a message about being below minimum specs (as expected.)

I upgraded the system memory to 2G and tried to attach the VGA cable to a external screen at 1024x768 but when I go into the game I get a "video unsupported" message by the display.

Can anyone provide steps/help to get this to run?

Comment: The comments on the youtube mention that the framerate is too low to play the game comfortably. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Did you upgrade the video driver?

Comment: You don't want to do this, try and get your hands on a pc / laptop on which you can run it more comfortably.

Comment: If you do ever get this running, please post an update here to let us know how it does!

Comment: @Seamus: I realize it's not ranked-game playable but I travel frequently and thought it might be fun to practice strategy with the AI when I can't play on my home system.  @Eric: Good idea, I'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds to me like your video card is outputting a signal/resolution not supported by your monitor. Assuming it's only losing the signal when you launch game, try tweaking the resolution manually:

in Documents/Starcraft II/Variables.txt

add...

```
width=1024
height=768
```

or whatever settings that you want to try.

Also, here are some other settings you can try tweaking in that file and see if you can gain some more performance:

> `foliagedensity (Default 0.750000)`
>
> It shows how dense the different
>   foliage elements like grass, leaves
>   will appear. You can decrease the
>   value to something that fit your needs
>   and also increase the performance of
>   the game.
>
> `parallaxshadow (Default 1)`
>
> Parallax Shadows give depth to game
>   textures and geometry at the expense
>   of CPU/GPU performance. Switching it
>   off by giving it ’0′ value may
>   increase performance of the game.
>
> `particlelod (Default 3)`
>   `particleobjects (Default 1.000000)`
>   `particleterrain (Default 1.000000)`
>
> These three commands govern the
>   quality of the particles in game.
>   Lower the values to get performance
>   boast.
>
> `shadowmapsize (Default 2048)`
>
> How shodows will be rendered in game,
>   lowering this value to 1024/512 will
>   increase the performance of the game
>   and also take off some load on GPU and
>   Ram.
>
> `TerrainTextureHiResCacheSize (Default 24)`
>   `TerrainTextureLowResCacheSize (Default 50)`
>
> These two variables control the amount
>   of memory the game uses to cache and
>   stream textures high and low
>   resolution textures separately.
>
> `TerrainTextureSize (Default 1024)`
>
> This is the memory of your graphic
>   card, memory available at the disposal
>   for the game to utilize.
>
> `transparentshadows (Default 1)`
>
> This is an eye candy tweak, if enabled
>   it will give shadows a transparent
>   touch enhancing colors in the process.
>   Its OK to change the value to ’0′, its
>   not something you need really. Infact,
>   its an effect you will hardly notice
>   while playing the game.
>
> `watercaustics (Default 1)`
>
> It makes the water look real, waves
>   effects and splashes on the surface of
>   water. Not required if you have low
>   end GPU. Set this value to ’0′ to turn
>   it off.
>
> `waterreflection (Default 1)`
>
> This variable enabled the reflection
>   on the surface of water. Again, not
>   required for people on low end graphic
>   cards.
>
> `waterrendertargetsize (Default 1024)`
>
> How the game will render everything
>   water, lower the value to boast
>   performance.
>
> **Source**:
>   http://segmentnext.com/2010/08/07/starcraft-2-graphics-performance-tweak-guide/

Comment: Nick: I'm curious to know if manually setting the resolution fixed your external monitor issue?